# Converting time to specific GMT in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do I convert the current time on my PC into a different GMT time in vb.net? For example, if the time right now is 22:00 in GMT-7, how could I convert that time to GMT+9? I have tried converting each number by hand (adding 16 to the current hour and adding to the days and hours and so on, but it is not really efficient and effective. Is there a easier way to do this?

Comment: `dim utcTime as DateTimeOffset = DateTime.UtcNow dim offset = utcTime.ToOffset(new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0))`

Comment: Or `dim zoneInfoOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time"))`, if you know the destination time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but when finding specific time zones if you know the exact reference time zone you can use this, which is from the Microsoft docs [located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc?view=netframework-4.8)

```
    Module Example
   Public Sub Main()
      ' Get time in local time zone 
      Dim thisTime As Date = Date.Now
      Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} zone: {1}", IIf(TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(thisTime), 
                        TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName, TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName), thisTime)
      Console.WriteLine("   UTC Time: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local))
      ' Get Tokyo Standard Time zone
      Dim tst As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time")
      Dim tstTime As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst)      
      Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} zone: {1}", IIf(tst.IsDaylightSavingTime(tstTime), 
                        tst.DaylightName, tst.StandardName), tstTime)
      Console.WriteLine("   UTC Time: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(tstTime, tst))
   End Sub
End Module
' The example displays output like the following when run on a system in the U.S.
' Pacific Standard Time zone:
'    Time in Pacific Standard Time zone: 12/6/2013 10:57:51 AM
'       UTC Time: 12/6/2013 6:57:51 PM
'    Time in Tokyo Standard Time zone: 12/7/2013 3:57:51 AM
'       UTC Time: 12/6/2013 6:57:51 PM
```